# How do I (manually) calculate bitwise and and bitwise or between two numbers in hexadecimal form without converting it into binary at any step?

Tags: bit-manipulation, hex

Lets say `a = 0x6db7` and `b = 0x736`.How to compute `a&b` and `a|b` manually?

I am aware of bitwise operations,and I know this can be solved by converting `a` and `b` into it's binary form and then bitwise operations and then again converting to hex,however what I am looking for is a  solution that doesn't involve too much of calculation  without the interdemidiate binary conversion.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Isn't that just the same as saying "What is the answer for Exam question number 8?" ;p

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: @Lucifer:No,it's precisely 'How can I answer question number 8 efficiently?'Since  I know how to do this in the usual way ... convert into binary and then standard bitwise operations.

Comment: Are we to assume that a and b are strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are bitwise `and` and bitwise `or`. To compute them manually, convert each number to binary, then compute the result. The result of an `and` will be 1 if and only if the corresponding bits are set. The result of an `or` will be 1 if the corresponding bits in either one or the other or both are set:

```
 100111      100111
&110010     |110010
-------     -------
 100010      110111
```

After that, you normally want to convert the result back to some other base (e.g., hexadecimal).

Comment: I am aware of this method,is it possible to solve without the intermediate binary conversion?

Comment: Possible, yes. Reasonable, probably not. The obvious possibility would be to memorize the entire table for all 16 hex digits. When I was writing assembly language on a regular basis I pretty much knew that, but but I don't work with such things nearly as often anymore.